# Python sees property as function

Tags: c#, com, python-2.7

I have a library written in C# and it goes like this

```
class FooCollection
    {
        private readonly FooBase _innerFoo;
        public FooCollection()
        {
            _innerFoo = new FooBase();
        }

        public string this[int index]
        {
            get { return _innerFoo._components[index].ComponentName; }
            set
            {
                _innerFoo._components[index].ComponentName = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this class is COM visible and I'm trying to use it from Python.
So, this command works

```
foo(1)
```

but this one doesn't

```
foo(1) = 'SomeName'
```

It gives me "can't assign to call function". I tried square brackets [], but that is no good.
Is there any way to bypass this, except me making additional 'normal' method in C# to set this property?

I'm using pywin32-218 for COM in Python.

```
foo = win32com.client.Dispatch("Foo")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexed property translates into `IL`, like

`FooCollection.get_Item` and `FooCollection.set_Item`, so probabbly in the final COM object 
translated too.

Try to use these function calls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Something like that. It was 'Set' without underscore. I have the same problem in Matlab, and there I have to use '.set('PropertyName', index, value)'. Thank you very much!